# Making Thread-Safe Calls by using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading

i want to use BackgroundWorker for my code.

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;

        }
        else
        {
            hladat();
        }

    }
```

and my function hladat() is

```
            int x = 0;


            while (x < 130)
            {

                for (trackBar7.Value = x; trackBar7.Value < 250-x; trackBar7.Value += 2)
                {
                    minR = trackBar7.Value;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);

                    if (((CV - CV / 4) < RV) && (RV < CV)&&(vyhovujedlzka()))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                trackBar7.Value = x;
                minR = x;

                for (trackBar8.Value = 250 - x; trackBar8.Value > x; trackBar8.Value -= 2)
                {
                    maxR = trackBar8.Value;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);

                    if (((CV - CV / 4) < RV) && (RV < CV) && (vyhovujedlzka()))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                trackBar8.Value = 250-x;
                maxR = 250-x;

                for (trackBar9.Value = 0; trackBar9.Value < 254; trackBar9.Value += 2)
                {
                    minG = trackBar9.Value;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);

                    if (((CV - CV / 4) < RV) && (RV < CV) && (vyhovujedlzka()))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if (((CV - CV / 4) < RV) && (RV < CV) && (vyhovujedlzka()))
                {
                    break;
                }
                x = x + 10;
                trackBar9.Value = 0;
                minG = 0;


        }
```

and when i start bgWorker it give me error for this part of code

trackBar7.Value = x

"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'trackBar7' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

how can i repair this code???... thnx and sorry for my english =//

Answer (score 3):

Set WorkerReportsProgress() to True for your BackgroundWorker() control, then wire up the ProgressChanged() event.

Now change:

```
trackBar7.Value = x;
```

To:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(x, trackBar7);
```

In the ProgressChanged() event, cast `e.UserState` back to TrackBar and set its Value() to `e.Percentage`:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TrackBar tb = (TrackBar)e.UserState;
        tb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

**Alternate approach:**

If you want to do it all from within hladat() itself, change:

```
        trackBar7.Value = x;
```

To:

```
        trackBar7.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{
            trackBar7.Value = x;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Use this function to set the value:

```
delegate void SetValueCallback(TrackBar trackbar, int value);

private void SetValue(TrackBar trackbar, int value)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (trackbar.InvokeRequired)
    {   
         SetValueCallback d = new SetValueCallback(SetValue);
         this.Invoke(d, new object[] {trackbar, value });
    }
    else
    {
         trackbar.Value = value;
    }
 }
```

This should correct the `set` part.

As for the reading; it's best to write the `Value` to a variable. In that case you won't need to access a UI-control for you logic, just read the variable.

Something like:

```
for (int c = x; c < 250-x; c += 2)
{
    SetValue(trackBar7, c); 
    //etc.
```

Comment: i write this before function         
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
but i have got still error for new SetTextCallback(SetValue);
No overload for 'SetValue' matches delegate 'webcam.Form1.SetTextCallback'

Comment: @Palike; sorry, my bad. I haven't tested it. I update the code with the correct callback. You can delete the SetTextCallback delegate. Let me know if it works out. If it doesn't i'll need to set up a test app to get the syntax right ;-)

Comment: thnx man !! it works... but you forgot to put d in line 
SetValueCallback = new SetValueCallback(SetValue);

Comment: @Palike: thanks for the correction. I updated the post. Don't forget to mark it as an answser if it is ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, either do the `Invoke` method [Stefan mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080126/80274), `ReportProgress` like [Idle_Mind mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080380/80274), or another option is to use [`IProgress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if you are on .NET 4.0 you can get the classes and interfaces from the [Microsoft.Bcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl) NuGet package).

The way it works is you create a [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object and set it up to do whatever update you need on the UI thread (it captures the `SynchronizationContext` of the thread it is currently running on when you create it, so create it on the UI thread), you then pass a `IProgress<T>` interface to the method you doing the updating and that method calls `Report(T)`

```
private Form1()
{
    //Snip

    trackBar7Progress = new Progress<int>(value => trackBar7.Value = value);
    trackBar8Progress = new Progress<int>(value => trackBar8.Value = value);
    trackBar9Progress = new Progress<int>(value => trackBar9.Value = value);
}

IProgress<int> trackBar7Progress;
IProgress<int> trackBar8Progress;
IProgress<int> trackBar9Progress;
```

then inside `hladat()` change your `trackBar#.Value = x` calls to `trackBar#Progress.Report(x)`

```
//Snip

trackBar7Progress.Report(x);
minR = x;

for (trackBar8.Value = 250 - x; trackBar8.Value > x; trackBar8.Value -= 2)
{
    maxR = trackBar8.Value;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);

    if (((CV - CV / 4) < RV) && (RV < CV) && (vyhovujedlzka()))
    {
        break;
    }
}

trackBar8Progress.Report(250-x);
maxR = 250-x;

for (trackBar9.Value = 0; trackBar9.Value < 254; trackBar9.Value += 2)
{
    minG = trackBar9.Value;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);

    if (((CV - CV / 4) < RV) && (RV < CV) && (vyhovujedlzka()))
    {
        break;
    }

}

if (((CV - CV / 4) < RV) && (RV < CV) && (vyhovujedlzka()))
{
    break;
}
x = x + 10;
trackBar9Progress.Report(0);
minG = 0;
```

Comment: i have got the same error whit this... Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'trackBar7' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Then either you are not creating the `Progress` object on the main thread or `trackBar7` is being created on a thread other than the main thread.